# Find python header path from within python?

Tags: python, numpy, header-files

What is the equivalent of

```
numpy.get_include()
```

as used [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html?highlight=get_include#instant) for Python, giving me the path to the directory where the Python header files are located?

Comment: why don't you just install numpy?

Comment: @Rachel Gallen This is not a numpy installation problem. I just used numpy as an example of what I am after...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The header files are in include directory.

You can find the include dir using the distutils.sysconfig module

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc
get_python_inc() #this gives the include dir
```

You can read about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#preprocessor-options)